# Creating columns by counting occurence number of a categorizing variable

Tags: r, count, indicator

I want to create several variables which count the occurrence times of `var`'s value for each `user.id`. Here is an example:

```
user.id     var
  1          A
  1          B
  2          A
  2          A
  2          C
  3          C
```

Expected result:

```
user.id     var_A    var_B     var_C
  1          1         1         0
  2          2         0         1
  3          0         0         1
```

Comment: `table(df$user.id, df$var)`

Comment: Just do `dcast(df1, user.id~var, length)`

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    count(user.id, var) %>% 
    spread(var, n, fill = 0)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  user.id     A     B     C
#*   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1       1     1     1     0
#2       2     2     0     1
#3       3     0     0     1
```

---

Or a more efficient approach with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), user.id ~ var)
```